# Cannot connect simple Java Smack example to Google Talk

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, google-talk

I have followed a series of tutorials and have come up with a very simple and minimalistic Java app that should connect to google talk and allow me to send message to an account.

I have turned off the SASLAuth security settings in order to make the example work, however when I try to connect to google servers, I get a complex TLS error and I think  that I am forced to enable the SASLAuth security settings. However, if I enable them, I get yet another error. Here are very simple code samples I am using. What am I missing?

**XmppManager.java**:

```
package try2;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence.Type;

public class XmppManager {

    private static final int packetReplyTimeout = 500; // millis

    private String server;
    private int port;
    private String service;

    private ConnectionConfiguration config;
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    private ChatManager chatManager;
    private MessageListener messageListener;

    public XmppManager(String aServer, int aPort, String aService) {
        server = aServer;
        port = aPort;
        service = aService;
    }

    public XmppManager(String server, int port) {
        this(server, port, null);
    }

    public void init() throws XMPPException {

        System.out.println(String.format("Initializing connection to server " +  server + ", port " + port 
                + ", service " + service));

        SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(packetReplyTimeout);

        if(service != null)
            config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port, service);
        else
            config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port);

        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        System.out.println("Connected: " + connection.isConnected());

        chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
        messageListener = new MyMessageListener();

    }

    public void performLogin(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            connection.login(username, password);
        }
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean available, String status) {

        Presence.Type type = available? Type.available: Type.unavailable;
        Presence presence = new Presence(type);

        presence.setStatus(status);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);

    }

    public void destroy() {
        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message, String buddyJID) throws XMPPException {
        System.out.println(String.format("Sending message " + message + " to user " + buddyJID));
        Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(buddyJID, messageListener);
        chat.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public void createEntry(String user, String name) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(String.format("Creating entry for buddy " + user + " with name " + name));
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        roster.createEntry(user, name, null);
    }

    public void printRoster() throws Exception {
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();  
        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Buddy:" + entry.getName() + " - Status:" + entry.getStatus()));
        }
    }


    private class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            String from = message.getFrom();
            String body = message.getBody();
            System.out.println(String.format("Received message " + body + " from " + from));
        }

    }

}
```

**XmppTest.java**:

```
package try2;

public class XmppTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String username = "user1";
        String password = "user1.pass";

        XmppManager xmppManager = new XmppManager("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");

        xmppManager.init();
        xmppManager.performLogin(username, password);
        xmppManager.setStatus(true, "Hello everyone");

        String buddyJID = "user2";
        String buddyName = "user2";
        xmppManager.createEntry(buddyJID, buddyName);

        xmppManager.sendMessage("Hello mate", "user2@gmail.com");

        xmppManager.printRoster();

        boolean isRunning = true;

        while (isRunning) {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }

        xmppManager.destroy();

    }

}
```

I think the error is related to these two code lines:

```
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
```

However if it is, then I have no idea how to configure them correctly !

**Error with SASLAuth disabled**:

```
Initializing connection to server talk.google.com, port 5222, service gmail.com
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TLS required by server but not allowed by connection configuration
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.startTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:768)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parseFeatures(PacketReader.java:414)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:254)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:46)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:72)
Connected: true
Exception in thread "main" No response from the server.: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:73)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:252)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:366)
    at try2.XmppManager.performLogin(XmppManager.java:70)
    at try2.XmppTest.main(XmppTest.java:13)
```

**Error with SASLAuth enabled**:

```
Exception in thread "main" SASL authentication PLAIN failed: invalid-authzid: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:342)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:243)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:366)
    at try2.XmppManager.performLogin(XmppManager.java:70)
    at try2.XmppTest.main(XmppTest.java:13)
```

Comment: Did any of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756432/connect-to-google-talk-using-smack help?

Comment: Nope, none of them worked. Probably different smack versions :S

Answer (score 1):

change the two lines with

```
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get `SASL authentication PLAIN failed: invalid-authzid:` error, even though I know the password for user1 is correct :S

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable "Access for less secure apps" in your Google account for simple username/password login. Or you need to implement OAUTH2 authentication using user ID and access token.